# Capistrano deployment with rsync

Tags: deployment, capistrano, rsync

I am trying to deploy apps from my dev machine using capistrano and rsync.
I have studied that rsync is used for backup and only copies bytes that are changed in the file. But to fit it as capistrano task.

A sample deploy code with rsync, with explanation would be be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this following links help you understand the code samples:-

http://philtoland.com/post/448916606/capistrano-deployment-using-rsync

have you checked this :-

https://github.com/vigetlabs/capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache

Answer (score 1):

If you soon end up using Capistrano v3 (v3.0.0pre14 as of right now), the good old Rsync support gem [capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache](https://github.com/vigetlabs/capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache) won't work. I recently created the spiritual success to that called [Capistrano::Rsync](https://github.com/moll/capistrano-rsync) which you might want to try.