# Deploy rails application with FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, web-deployment

I have my virtual private server and I pointed a domain name to `/var/www/vhosts`. I have my Rails app in my local system. After I transfer my file through FTP how can I run my Rails app in production mode?

Most of the tutorials are about deploying with capistrano. Since I don't have a private git repo I am not interested in using capistrano.

Comment: You probably SHOULD be interested in using capistrano. Especially if the alternative is using FTP to copy files over. You do realize that there are things that need command line access on the server you are deploying to?

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano as I remember does support deployment from other sources apart from repositories.
In one production scenario while back we used to deploy from a local admin server to clusters.
Low level was either using rsync/ftp don't recollect.

here is a related post:
[Capistrano deployment with rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118473/capistrano-deployment-with-rsync)

Please do post your findings on other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Git? If yes, you can use this Ruby tool to deploy though FTP:

There are three git-ftp scripts which allow you to "push" a git repository to a FTP server.

- [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy)

There other such tools in other languages too if you prefer a script written in Bash, Python or PHP.

If you are not using Git, I strongly suggest you start using it.